# Creating a function to Find a range of values in a distribution vector

Tags: r

Creating a function where I pass four arguments- three to create a normal distribution vector and a fourth which is a percent distance from the mean of the distribution. Trying to get this function to output the number of values in the percentage range (percentdist.arg) passed to the function.

```
rnormfunc <- function(n.arg, mean.arg, sd.arg, percentdist.arg){  

rnorm1 <- rnorm(n.arg, mean.arg, sd.arg) 
j <- (percentdist.arg/100)  # changes percent distance into decimal value
b <- mean.arg*(1+j)  # max percent distance from mean
g <- mean.arg*(1-j) # min percent distance from mean
total.in.range <- sum(rnorm1 %in% g:b) # sum of rnorm1 values between g:b
return(total.in.range)                
}
```

My function is not producing an rnorm1 vector of values- I'm fundamentally missing something here! Should I be using the which() function?

Comment: You need `(rnorm1 > g & rnorm1 < b)` instead of `g:b`.   `g:b` creates a sequence from `g` to `b`, with interval 1.  And `%in%` it TRUE if your rnorm1 equals one of the sequence, which rarely happens since rnorm1 is a continuous variable.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kota Mori's comment, using this should work:

`total.in.range <- sum(rnorm1 > g & rnorm1 < b)`